# How to cut onion into small cubes?

Tags: food, kitchen

Do you know any tricks how to cut the onion into small cubes?

I've tried many times, but my girlfriend always complains that they're too big:)

Similar:

- [How can I cut onions without tearing up?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/2531/how-can-i-cut-onions-without-tearing-up)

Comment: I'm tempted to answer "with a knife" ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do it like I do (and Jamie O.)

Slice the onion in two. Then, make slices but not cut the onion entirely, so they the ends are still connected. Make horizontal cuts if you want really small cubes. Then, cut perpendicular to the first slices until you are almost done. Then turn the onion (as it will be smaller then the height) so it is flat again. Make your final cuts.

See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZQZtCVkypAo around 2m

Answer (score 2):

after pealing and trimming the top and bottom, slice the onion in half along the top/bottom axis. then turn each half flat side down, and make a series of cuts parallel to that top/bottom axis. Make them as close as you want. Then make a series of cuts perpendicular to the top/bottom axis, spaced similarly to the previous parallel cuts.

A sharp knife helps a lot, as usual.

Answer (score 1):

Place it on the board as it stand. 
Slice them top to bottom like parallel ways then cute them to smaller :)

Answer (score 1):

Or you could pick the lazy way.

- Peel the onion (cut into half or quarters if necessary)
- Add the onion to a multi mixer
- Slowly mix away until you have the preferred size

Advantages: Quick easy, no smelly hands, no tears and no more cuts!

Answer (score 0):

1. Turn the onion so that the tapered side sits to your right and chop off the right and left ends (vertical cut) and peel the onion off by removing the outer skin.
2. Set the onion on one of the flat sides and cut it into thin slices vertically.
3. Cut each slice separately by making a grid (cut it horizontally and vertically). You can use few slices of the same size at the same time (on top of each other). Usually most of the onion will come apart in layers that make nice arches.
4. When all slices are cut, perform extra chopping.

Now you've perfect small cubes.

Alternatively use the grate and chop it at the end.

Related:

- [How to Cut an Onion](http://www.wikihow.com/Cut-an-Onion) at wikiHow